# Why vscode doesn't intellisense function inside packages in typescript monorepo?

Tags: node.js, typescript, visual-studio-code, lerna, monorepo

I created a monorepo with lerna ([the code in github](https://github.com/wizardnet972/lerna-test)).

Inside I have two packages each package export `sum` function.

In `app1` folder I want to import this function but vscode doesn't find the function.

Not sure why. I set everything correctly, and vscode should be offer from two paths:

```
@packages/pck1
@packages/pck2
```

**/tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.build.json",

  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@packages/*": ["packages/*/src"]
    },
    "jsx": "react",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "types": []
  }
}
```

If you can clone my repo - run `npm install` then open vscode and go to `apps/app1/src/index.ts` and write `sum`. wait for typescript to find the function. you will get:

[image]

can't find the reason, any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using scoped packages, they would be called `@pck1` and `@pck2`, not `@packages/SOMETHING` as your top-level `tsconfig.json` suggests.

I could get your example working as follows:

Add these `compilerOptions` to `apps/app1/tsconfig.json`:

```
"baseUrl": ".",
"paths": {
  "@pck1": ["../../packages/pck1/src"]
}
```

And change `apps/app1/src/index.ts`:

```
import { sum } from '@pck1';
sum(9,9);
```

Your basic mistake is: You consider `packages` part of the packages' names but it is just a directory. I have created a PR on github for this: https://github.com/wizardnet972/lerna-test/pull/1

I have a similar lerna test project on github: https://github.com/gflohr/lerna-deps. It is explained in a blog post http://www.guido-flohr.net/lerna-mono-repos-with-internal-dependencies/. Maybe you can use that as a starting point.